# phpmysqladmin procedure comment

Tags: mysql

I'm using phpMySQLAdmin to create procedure with comments in it.

But phpmysqladmin strip away comment before it sends sql to server, I don't know how to get comment into my stored procedure using phpmysqladmin. Does anyone know?

Comment: can you place the code that you are using?

Comment: DROP PROCEDURE `test`//
  # MySQL comment
  /* comment */
  CREATE  PROCEDURE `test`(  )
  BEGIN 
  select 1 from table;  -- comment
  end

Answer (score 1):

What version of phpMyAdmin are you using? It [appears](http://freecode.com/projects/phpmyadmin/releases/307498) this may be a bug in some versions. I would recommend you try a different client. Perhaps MySQL Workbench?

Comment: +1 for pointing out the bug report, and also +1 for recommending alternative tools.

Comment: Not sure how to find out. But it's on the hosted sever, and I do not have a choice to install MySql workbench

Comment: MySQL Workbench runs on your desktop/laptop and you connect to your host through it. Alternatively, you can upload the latest version of phpMyAdmin to your website.